# Insert element inside a div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 6 images that page using .cycle

The main image is under the #up div that is automatically generated, but I want to add the .thumbnail class to the #up image or insert it

```
$(function() {
        $('#up').after('<ul id="slide">').cycle({
            fx:     'fade',
            speed:  'fast',
            timeout: 0,
            pager:  '#slide',
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
                return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="100" height="100" /></a></li>';
            }
        });
        $('#up').children('img').addClass('.thumbnail');
    });
```

Here is the page I am working on if you want a good chuckle -

http://homeplan.com/HPS%20LP/work.html

Joey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, when using `addClass()` you don't need to type the typically starting dot for classes, so do like this:

```
$('#up').children('img').addClass('thumbnail');
```

Comment: Thanks @Nelson ! Any idea why the #up image wouldn't scale according to the .thumbnail properties of bootstrap?

Comment: I don't see you're adding the thumbnail class (i.e. my above code) anywhere in your page. Also, you have this wrong code `$('up').appendTo('#show');` , I think you meant `$('#up').appendTo('#show');`

Comment: Sorry the page wasn't updated. Your code is now in there

http://homeplan.com/HPS%20LP/work.html

Joey